# pandas: dataframe to_csv, how to set column names

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
myseries=pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
df=pd.DataFrame(myseries)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Output:

```
      0
0    0.51..
1    0.14..
2    -0.68..
3    0.48..
4    1.89..
```

I want the column name to be "values" instead of 0. How can I do that?
I suppose that I should replace the last statement with df.to_csv("output.csv", columns = ["values"]). But I got the keyerror:
`u"None of [['values']] are in the [columns]"`
I don't know what that means.

**[update]**
Many answers say that I should use `df.columns=['values']`. Well, that does not work for me. I concern not only what the dataframe is like, but also what the csv file is like. The dataframe looks all right, but the csv file is not. That's the confusing part.

```
...
df.columns=["values"]
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

It says:`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output.csv'`.
I then use the absolute path "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\output.csv", the error is like: `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\output.csv'`
I don't know why this error, but this is rather confusing.
For further information, I installed anaconda-2.7 on win10. I tested the code with spyder.

Comment: df.columns=['values']

Comment: `df.columns = ['values']`

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['values'])`

Comment: If `Permission denied` try close file before writing or maybe some another `permission` problem

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to save heading? I am experiencing the same problem: when using 'df.to_csv' the headings are not saved to the CVS file. Thank

Comment: <p> @Confounded I had the same issue. This the way way i overcame it while saving it to file:`csv_data = df.to_csv(header=['COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2'])`
You need to explicitly re-mention the colmun names else it saved as 0,1,.. and so forth.

Not sure what is the reason for this thing to happen. Haven't been able to find anyone else coming across such issue or resolving it either.

Answer (score 28):

You can set column name in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['values'])
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':myseries})
print (df)
     values
0 -0.429758
1 -0.019931
2  1.189596
3  1.309223
4 -0.337061

df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Or set parameter `header` in [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myseries)
df.to_csv("output.csv", header=['values'])
```

Or in [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html):

```
myseries.to_csv("output.csv", header=['values'])
```

Answer (score 6):

To set the column name to 'values' try:

```
df.columns = ['values']
```

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with your issues:

1. Column rename - I've found on Python 3.6+ with compatible Pandas versions that `df.columns = ['values']` works fine in the output to csv. Note that does not give the index column a heading (see 3 below)
2. Permission issues when writing the output.csv file - this almost always relate to having the csv file open in a spreadsheet or editor.  You also sometimes get a silent fail where it says it wrote but the csv stayed the same.  Failing that, check directory and file permissions where you are storing the file.  Some operating systems like you to create the file first (`touch output.csv`).  If you are running the python from a cron or other batch file, check what user is running the code and check that user's permissions.
3. Naming the index column - *if* you want to give the index a name then use `df.to_csv("output.csv", index_label="whatever_name_you_want")`